# How to adjust the height of a Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website based on [W3 Schools' Bootstrap Company Theme](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp), which I've shared at https://github.com/khpeek/peek-solutions. (A previous version is online at [www.peek.solutions](http://www.peek.solutions/)). Here is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
  <title>Peek Solutions</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      /*color: #818181;*/
      color: #181818;
  }
  h2 {
      font-size: 24px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }  
  .jumbotron {
        background-image: url("img/Patagonia_Sirona_crop3.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center bottom;
      /*background-color: #050042;*/
      color: #fff;
      padding: 70px 25px;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .container-fluid {
      padding: 60px 50px;
  }
  .bg-grey {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
  .logo-small {
      color: #050042;
      font-size: 50px;
  }
  .logo {
      color: #050042;
      font-size: 200px;
  }
  .thumbnail {
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
  }
  .thumbnail img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
      background-image: none;
      color: #050042;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
      border-color: #050042;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li.active {
      background-color: #050042;
  }
  .item h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: italic;
      margin: 70px 0;
  }
  .item span {
      font-style: normal;
  }
  .panel {
      border: 1px solid #050042; 
      border-radius:0 !important;
      transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  .panel:hover {
      box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  }
  .panel-footer .btn:hover {
      border: 1px solid #050042;
      background-color: #fff !important;
      color: #050042;
  }
  .panel-heading {
      color: #fff !important;
      background-color: #050042 !important;
      padding: 25px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .panel-footer {
      background-color: white !important;
  }
  .panel-footer h3 {
      font-size: 32px;
  }
  .panel-footer h4 {
      color: #aaa;
      font-size: 14px;
  }
  .panel-footer .btn {
      margin: 15px 0;
      background-color: #050042;
      color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      /*background-color: #818181;*/
      z-index: 9999;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #050042 !important;
      background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  footer .glyphicon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      color: #050042;
  }
  .slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
  .slide {
      animation-name: slide;
      -webkit-animation-name: slide;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      visibility: visible;
  }
  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 150px;
    }
  }

  #accordion {text-align: left};
  </style>
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

<!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Peek Solutions</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Peek Solutions</h1> 
  <p>Pipeline integrity solutions for the energy industry.</p> 
  <!-- <form class="form-inline">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
  </form> -->
</div>

<!-- Container (About Section) -->
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>About us</h2><br>
      <h4>Peek Solutions, an independent consulting company founded by Ralf Peek, provides pipeline integrity solutions and assurance support to the energy industry, including the application of structural reliability methods to assess and ensure integrity.</h4><br>
      <!-- <p>Peek Consulting is a consulting company founded by Ralf Peek.</p> -->
      <br>
      <!-- <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get in Touch</button> -->
      <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button">Get in touch</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p><center><strong>This website is currently under construction.</strong></center></p>
      <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal logo"> This website is under construction</span> -->
      <img src="img/under_construction.jpg"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Services Section) -->
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>Our services include:</h4>
  <br>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Pipeline Integrity Assessment and Design</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Our services include the design and assessment of subea pipelines for lateral and/or upheaval buckling, arctic pipelines subject to ice gouging, stamukha loadings and/or thaw settlements, and pipelines crossing active faults, as well as more routine design/assessment.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Structural Reliability Assessment (SRA)</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Ralf Peek has over 30 years of experience in the area of structural reliability assessment and the estimation and assessment of uncertainties affecting structural performance in order to ensure that safety margins are adequate to cover such uncertainties, including:
        <ul>
            <li>Reliability-based design of buried arctic subsea pipeline against loading by ice keels gouging the sea floor.</li>
            <li>SRA for pipelines subject to lateral buckling under thermal expansion.</li>
            <li>Operating pipelines subject to extreme conditions (for example, turbidity current loading).</li>
            <li>Probabilistic response-based seismic loading assessment criteria.</li>
            <li>Nuclear containment structure reliability assessment.</li>
            <li>Peek Solutions can also coordinate and deliver Quantitative Risk Assessment (QRA), where necessary arranging for inputs on hydrocarbon release modeling from others.  (QRA includes assessment of the consequences of failure as well as the probability of occurrence, and typically involves integration of muti-disciplinary inputs, as well as inputs based on local knowledge into a model.)</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Reasons to  perform a Structural Reliability Analysis (SRA) or Quantitative Risk Asessment (QRA)  could include:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Extreme loadings are encountered such as ice, or geohazard loadings for which there are no established design methods and criteria.</li>
            <li>Operating conditions (e.g. wet, sour service) can strongly affect the deformation capacity of the pipe.</li>
            <li>Consequences of failure could be exceptionally severe.</li>
            <li>New technology or a new concept is being used for which there is limited experience, and ingredient uncertainties affecting the performance are different from those for standard technology.</li>
            <li>Where new, more reliable technology, inspection or assessment methods are used whereby uncertainties are reduced, and an adjustment in the required safety margins could be justified.</li>
            <li>Value of information analysis under uncertainty in essence consists of performing SRA or QRA with and without the information so that the value of the information can be assessed.  Such “information” might consist for instance of a (full scale) testing program, or other investigation to reduce uncertainties.</li>
            <li>The loading for a pipeline is somewhere in between load- and displacement-controlled, so that existing criteria for either of these cases is not directly applicable, and a case-specific calibration of the required safety margins is needed.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>SRA and/or QRA ties together a number of aspects of design, specifications, fabrication and installation methods, monitoring, inspection and maintenance, and contingency response procedures, as all have a bearing on reliability.  To include all these aspects properly typically requires a muti-disciplinary team, with expertise that typically cannot be found within a single company.  Peek Solutions will assemble and engage such a team (e.g. by subcontracts), drawing from a network of specialists, as well as drawing from customer’s expertise, practices and procedures.</p>
        <p>In SRA’s statistical data are used to quantify uncertainties.  However in most cases there are important uncertainties for which statistical data are not available.  Indeed these dominate more often than not.  Ignoring such uncertainties, or making the SRA conditional upon certain assumptions about such uncertainties can be dangerous.  Therefore Peek Solutions will assess all uncertainties, rather than only the ones for which statistical data are available, and quantify them by informed engineering judgment supported, engaging external experts as appropriate.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Pipeline Design or Operational Integrity Review, Assurance and/or Specification</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Despite the guidance available from design codes, the design process relies significantly on engineering judgment to define suitable analysis methods, and the associated assumptions, and approximations.  Such judgments should be based on a knowledge of the conditions for which the safety margins in the design code have been calibrated, and how there may or may not differ from the conditions for the design under consideration.  Safe and economical design requires not only state-of-the-art or beyond analysis methods, but also to understand differences between model and real behavior, their impact, and safety margins needed to cover the associated uncertainties.  Peek Solutions can help to assure that such issues have been adequately addressed for pipeline designs where special challenges are involved.</p>
        <p>Design reviews can sometimes raise issues at a time when this can have a deleterious effect on project schedules.  A better alternative can be to develop a robust design approach from the onset. This can be done by engaging design review at the early stages, or even by developing a Design Specification prior to FEED (Front End Engineering Design) or detailed design.</p>
        <p>The Design Specification includes design code interpretation (if applicable), analysis methods, and assumptions and approximations to be made, together with a pertinent example to illustrate these.  Further it can include any testing programs, e.g. in the form of additional welding procedure qualification requirements to assure girth weld integrity understrain based design conditions, or special in-situ tests to reduce uncertainty associated with pipe-soil interaction.  Where necessary the safety margins in the Design Specification are calibrated based on structural reliability assessment to ensure that a specified target reliability level is achieved.</p>
        <p>In addition to design, Peek Solutions supports installation (where this can affect performance), and specification and interpretation of as-built and/or as-laid surveys.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Concept Definition and Assessment</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p>In some cases it may be expedient to perform quick evaluations of a number of concepts in order to focus on the most promising ones, or check the feasibility of an innovative one which could deliver considerable life-cycle savings, but for which there is limited or no experience.  Peek Solutions can help in this process to conceive, identify, and/or assess innovative concepts.  For instance Ralf Peek invented an effective method to reliably trigger lateral buckles in order to safely accommodate thermal expansion called the “Zero-Radius-Bend (ZRB)” method.  (See [ref] and/or search “ZRB pipeline” on the web for more information.)   This method has been successfully adopted for a number of of high-temperature subsea pipelines for Sarawak Shell and others.  According to a review of methods to trigger buckles for controlled thermal expansionby the Safebuck JIP [url], this ZRB is the only one with 100%  success in triggering the buckles as intended.</p>
        <p>To make innovation feasible, it needs to be assessed at an early stage.  Peek Solutions can help by developing and assessing a feasibility-basis design at a level of detail that is sufficient to expose any devil that may be hiding in the details.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Research and Development</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Peek Solutions’ ambition is to contribute to improved understanding and modeling for pipeline integrity assurance, not only by its own R&D efforts, but also by being at the interface between academic research and applications to the industry, in order to make better use of academic research, but also to influence academic research programs towards matters relevant to pipeline integrity.</p>
        <p>Structural Reliability Assessment (SRA) provides an excellent framework to capture and quantify improved knowledge from R&D programs in terms of reduced uncertainty.  The economic benefit this generates can then be assessed by a Value of Information Analysis (VIA).  Conversely, SRA and VIA can also point to areas where R&D is most fruitful.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Specialized Software Development</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Ralf Peek has experience with code development and application for Finite Element Analysis, having developed the NPEX code while at the University of Michigan. Using NPEX as a starting point, Peek Solutions can efficiently develop codes for specific applications, such as lateral buckling analysis, buried pipeline subject to ice loading or offset at a fault (with the soil modeled by springs), or calculation of pipe deformation capacity without local buckling.</p>
        <p>Experience also includes the development of a material subroutine, VUMAT, for ABAQUS/Explicit to model undrained or drained saturated soil behavior during ice gouging over a buried pipeline.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>



</div>

<!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Leersum, The Netherlands</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> +31 624272619</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <a href=mailto:ralf@peek.solutions>ralf@peek.solutions</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>

<!-- Add Google Maps -->
<!-- <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBimnrhiugaGSNN8WnsjpzMNJcrH_T60GI"></script>
<script>
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(52.010938, 5.437853);

function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:12,
  scrollwheel:false,
  draggable:false,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <a href="#myPage" title="To Top">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <!-- <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" title="Visit w3schools">www.w3schools.com</a></p> -->
</footer>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 900, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".slideanim").each(function(){
      var pos = $(this).offset().top;

      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 600) {
          $(this).addClass("slide");
        }
    });
  });
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to improve the appearance of the accordion. The individual 'boxes' of the accordion are quite high, and could fit ~3 lines of text. I would like to make them closer together such that they can fit ~1.5 line of text. What is the best way to achieve this? Should I adjust the `line-height` parameter of `h4` (see screenshot below)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

class `.panel-heading` has `25px` padding,but by default it is `padding: 10px 15px;`

so its overwritten.

**eg:**

[image]

Comment: +1  - For Bootstrap v5, I had to apply the padding style to `.accordion-button`, but it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You should just reduce/remove the padding attribute in .panel-heading class from your css. You can simply add these line of code

```
<style>
   .panel-heading{    
       padding: 0px; //if not working use !important rule
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the below property to your h4 element -

```
white-space: nowrap;
```